# libcurl https example error

Tags: c, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I downloaded and slightly adapted this c [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curl/curl/master/docs/examples/https.c) from the curl webpage. The test application uses my previously build curl.dll. I'm not able to connect to a https server without disabling the peer verification.

My original test application:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) 
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        printf ("res = %d curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",res, curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

The output is:

```
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (XX.XXX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
res = 60 curl_easy_perform() failed: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

If I download and store a [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) file from mozilla next to my exe and adapt the sample to:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) 
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, ".");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        printf ("res = %d curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",res, curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

I still get an error message

```
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (XX.XXX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
      CApath: .
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
res = 60 curl_easy_perform() failed: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

It is working fine if I disable peer verification.

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) 
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, ".");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        printf ("res = %d curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",res, curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes this behaviour? Do I have to set the peer certificate? I haven't found a setter for this.

Comment: https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the option **CAINFO**

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        printf ("res = %d curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",res, curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```